# Author deleted their question which I answered and he responded saying I answered his question

Tags: discussion

I answered a question, but then the author said I answered their question ("That is amazing, Great Work! I understand! Thank You!!"), and then they deleted their post.

I thought Stack Overflow doesn't allow an author to delete questions which have answers on them(?).

Comment: The prohibition only applies when there is a *positively-scored* answer. Yours hadn't gotten an upvote, so the asker was allowed to delete the question. Of course, the deletion was invalid, so I have undeleted it. Moderator flags are welcome in blatant cases like this.

Comment: Flag for the mods. You can flag the question, because you can see your deleted answer below the post. Mods can undelete their question. If the mods remains inactive, probably it can be undeleted also by 10k+ votes, but you need to somehow get the 3 undel vote (https://chat.stackoverflow.com), explain that it was a misuse deletion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: Why is that question off-topic?

Comment: @Peter One vote for "no longer reproducible", one vote for "lacks a minimal, reproducible example", and one vote for "unclear". As I'm not a Python programmer, I don't feel comfortable overriding this community-led closure. Your experience may guide you differently.